# Retrieving exact clients time in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

Till today I am using `DateTime.Now;` function to save the time and data of users. Well, at later stage I used JavaScript to get the client's date and time to maintain Time Zone. But when I change my system's date and time and try that JavaScript. It show the changed time of my computer. I need how to get clients correct current date and time value. How to get it.

Please do not exceed answer more than C# & JavaScripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client, when client send a request with javascript, get new Date().toJSON() value and send it to server. toJSON() returns current client datetime in GMT+0000 timezone (Greenwich):

```
var dtStr=new Date().toJSON();
```

On server, in C#:

```
DateTime dtServer=DateTime.Now;
DateTime dtClient=DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["dtStr"]); // Or Request.Form
double requestTimeDelta=10f; // max time in seconds between client starts the request,
                             // and this code lines is executed.
double secondsDelta=2f;
DateTime max=dtClient.AddSeconds(requestTimeDelta+secondsDelta);
DateTime min=dtClient.AddSeconds(-secondsDelta);
if (max>=dtServer && min<=dtServer) {
  // time is correct
}
else
{
  // time is incorrect
}
```

Above code is required, that time on client and on server has been synchronized with global clocks (internet timesource servers, for example). To avoid this problem you can calculate and save (in Session, for example) initial (on first request) difference between client and server clocks, and add this 'difference' to `max` and `min` variables. This behaviour is simply to coding, and not showed in code above.

Comment: I am getting this error. `Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.`

Comment: @Kars. I'm made correction to code. This is only for demonstrating, that `dtStr` request parameter must be passed to call of `.Parse` method.

Comment: I tried it before but I am getting this error `String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s`

Comment: Where is 'string reference not set...'? Request.QueryString["dtStr"] can return null, if no parameter `dtStr` is found in GET request. For POST requests use Request.Form["dtStr"]. `DateTime.Parse()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx.

Comment: Of course you are requesting a string. But you didn't pass string from JavaScript. How come `Reqyuest.QueryString` function works?

Comment: @Kars. Reread my first paragraph: _get new Date().toJSON() value and send it to server._ (you must send it! with javascript, as part of HTML FORM object, or as part of AJAX request). If you dont known how it to make - this is another question. I can demonstate some variants, but this is very depended on your real needs  `HttpRequest.QueryString()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When working with clients/servers from different time zones you should use [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

For example in C# use DateTime.UTCNow and not DateTime.UTC.
Along each time you save you should save the timezone as well, later on you'll be able to calculate the local time. It works also for daylight saving changes.

Comment: Well. This retrieve's time in UTC and how to convert time to client's time zone.

Comment: @Kars check my answer on how to get the offset for conversions

Answer (score 2):

**You seem to be asking "How do I determine the client's *real* timezone even when their computer's clock is set incorrectly?"** If so, please update your question to say so more clearly.

You can't do this from JavaScript: how could it know any time or timezone other than what the computer tells it (both of which are based on what the user has set)?

On the server-side you could try an IP-address to timezone mapping but really that's still just an educated *guess*. (Google it if you want to pursue it anyway.)

You could hack into their web-cam and hope that it is pointed at a clock on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` runs on the server and gets the datetime as configured on the server and not on the client.

You will have to use javascript to get the clients Time, you can pass the value via a hidden field which could be stored using `new Date()` method of javascript. to get the offset from GMT use `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` which would give the offset in minutes say like for + 1 GMT it would return -60.

It would be nice to maintain all datetime information in GMT format and then use the offset for client needs.

Comment: Well, while retrieving client's time and date. If user modifies his computer's time and date and uses this JavaScript. How can this JavaScript detect that user's time is wrong.

Comment: In that case there is no simple solution maybe you need to get the IP allocation and trace it to a timezone

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the actual machine time. You can attempt to calculate the timezone of the client and then adjust accordingly.

A quick search brought up [this post](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/) that implements a solution which addresses some of the problems with using the JavaScript `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Always maintain your datetime in one format on the server side. I prefer DateTimeOffset and that takes care of storing it in the right format for me.. You should definitely read up on that : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx

Regarding rendering it on the client side well you have two options:

A) Store the clients timezone in a cookie as and when he logs in and then use this timezone to  serve all your datetime to our client.

B) or you  need to perform your time voodoo on the client side for best results and this can be achieved using javascript. you need to make sure you pass one value (say UTC) back to your client and you need to parse your time to UTC too..

here is a neat function to parse your timeto UTC before sending it to the server

```
function getDateAsUTC(time, date) {
    var regExTime = /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})([AP]M)?$/i;
    var invalidTimeString="invalid time";
    if (segmentsTime = time.replace(" ", "").match(regExTime)) {
        if (segmentsTime[3]) {
            // 12-hour time format with am/pm
            if (parseInt(segmentsTime[1],10) < 1 || parseInt(segmentsTime[1],10) > 12) {
                time = invalidTimeString;
            }
        }
        else {
            // 24-hour time format
            if (parseInt(segmentsTime[1],10) > 23) {
                time = invalidTimeString;
            }
        }
        if (time !== invalidTimeString && parseInt(segmentsTime[2],10) > 59) {
            time = invalidTimeString;
        }
    }
    else {
        time = invalidTimeString;
    }

    if (time !== invalidTimeString) {
        var jsDateFriendlyTime = segmentsTime[1] + ":" + segmentsTime[2] + " " + segmentsTime[3];
        return new Date(date + " " + jsDateFriendlyTime).toGMTString().replace("UTC", "GMT");
    }
    else{
        return time; 
    }
}
```

and for rendering the time in the correct format you could use the [toLocaleDateString() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp).